# how do I style a ruby select in bootstrap?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, html-select

I want to wrap this line of ruby in a select style in bootstrap but every time I do it breaks and lists all the generated options outside the form.

Here in the code I want to wrap

```
<%= f.label :user_description_id %>
<%= f.collection_select(:user_description_id, UserDescription.all, :id, :description, include_blank: true) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing somethin linke this:

```
<%= f.label :user_description_id %>
<%= f.collection_select(:user_description_id, UserDescription.all, :id, :description, {include_blank: true}, {class: "css-class"} ) %>
```

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select